# Oracle Apex save date column value

Tags: date, oracle-apex

I have a table DATES with date columns as START_DATE and END_DATE.

Both have datatype as DATE.

In Interactive grid, `select start_date,end_date from dates;`

Both are set as date picker.

And the format mask is : DD-MON-RR.

In processing I have insert and update statements, but when i save the  grid, it throws error as invalid month.

```
INSERT INTO DATE (START_DATE,END_DATE) VALUES (:START_DATE,END_DATE);

UPDATE DATES
SET START_DATE = :START_DATE,
END_DATE = :END_DATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that any page item in apex is a string so when you execute

```
UPDATE DATES
SET START_DATE = :START_DATE,
END_DATE = :END_DATE;
```

this will rely on implicit conversion based on nls settings. It's a lot safer to include the format mask in your update statement:

```
apex_debug.info(
            p_message => 'velocity debug: START_DATE: %0,
            p0 => :START_DATE);
apex_debug.info(
            p_message => 'velocity debug: END_DATE: %0,
            p0 => :END_DATE);
UPDATE DATES
SET START_DATE = TO_CHAR(:START_DATE,'DD-MON-RR'),
END_DATE = TO_CHAR(:END_DATE,'DD-MON-RR');
```

Note the code instrumentation using the `apex_debug` api. These log entries will be visible in the apex debug logs and can be used to log any bind variable values during the execution of apex processes. To use the apex debugger, check my answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76733969/oracle-apex-ora-01403-no-data-found-for-form-update-action-if-user-is-not-in-w)

Comment: It still throws invalid number error. Is it because the database column has datatype set as DATE?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Invalid number is an unusual error for a date column, I suspect the error is thrown elsewhere but debug should give you more info