# Oracle Apex "ORA-01403" No Data Found for form update action if user is not in workspace?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a basic form in my Oracle APEX application that is updating a table in my parsing schema. If the user isn't added to the workspace, they cannot save their changes, even though they have access to view the application (and are granted edit rights per the authorization scheme).

I do not want to have to add every user to the workspace, as we're using an LDAP query for our access within the app.

I know this is possible as others are doing it without adding the users to the workspace as general users, but we can't identify the difference in configurations.

I have tried writing a custom merge statement instead of the generic form, and I've tried changing the parsing schema and pointing to the other schema manually. Neither solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not needed to have the users in the workspace. Why this behaviour is happening in your ... well that is up to you do debug.
Whenever you get an ORA error, the first thing to try is debug.

##### step 1: enable debug

Select "debug" from the developer toolbar, and click "Enable Debug" > "Info".

[image]

##### step 2: debug your page.

Now that you have debug enabled, execute the action that is causing the error. You state "cannot save their changes" so this is probably happening on page submit. Debugs are generated for page show, page submit and ajax calls.

Select "Debug" > "View Debug" from the developer toolbar. Make sure the filter shows your page id and look for the entry that was generated on page submit. A submit has "path Info" value "Accept ". Click on the view identifier for that entry and investigate the debug entries. The ORA error will show up in red. That should give you a hint about what is happening.

[image]